# Get all the indices of each unique row

Tags: matlab, for-loop, find, unique

I have a 4 column 2D matrix containing x, y, z coordinates and densities. All XYZ's have been forced to a nearest 500m value. I want to collect all row indices for all unique XYZ combinations.

So, I imagine that for an m x 4 matrix of densities, I should build up an m x n matrix with each row containing 1s and 0s for their relation to the density rows. I could then isolate all values for a unique XYZ for functions (ie: average or median).

I have used unique(dd(:,1:3, 'rows') to get the unique XYZ's. I can use ismember() to find for one row of unique XYZ. How would I run it for all rows of unique XYZ to produce that m x n matrix, without a for loop?

Comment: what do you mean by this ?"I should build up an m x n matrix with each row containing 1s and 0s for their relation to the density rows". If you can provide an example of what you are actually looking for it will be easier for people to help you!

Comment: KiW - since ismember() returns a vector of logicals indicating which row has the queried value, I imagined I needed to construct a matrix by adding a vector for each queried value as a row. Then I could multiply that matrix by the density column for a column vector of summed totals. Bit it looks like Dan sorted me. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the third output of the [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function which you can then feed to `accumarray`:

```
[~,~,subs] = unique(dd(:,1:3), 'rows')
```

then to find the medians

```
accumarray(subs, dd(:,4), [], @median)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked (when I changed the order of dd(:,4) and subs). I was confused by the repeating numbers in the "subs" but it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user24007 think of `subs` as an array of *groups* that `accumarray` will apply the function in the 4th argument (i.e. `@median`) to the corresponding elements of *each group* in the second argument, `dd(:,4)`.